# SDL_init() function makes debugging in VS laggy

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, sdl-1.2

I'm exploring a source code of xDuke in VS2013. When starting in debug mode I get an extremely slow VS environment (mouse pointer is VERY laggy). Putting break points at different places brought me to conclusion that the lagging begins after running SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) function. I use SDL 1.2.15 and win10.

Have anybody stumbled upon a similar situation? Where to start searching for a solution?

Thanks a lot!
Alexei

Answer (score 0):

I've migrated the code to SDL2. This solved the issue.